# Newtons First Law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Suppose there is a very very heavy object on a frictionless surface and if a force of a very small magnitude is applied to object will the object move?

What I believe is when I apply  a force to a object it means transfer of energy and since in a very heavy object mass is more, when energy is transferred through vibrations among  there can  be some loss of energy and if the force is very very small and if net energy results to be zero with in the object before making the object move then the  object won't end up moving.

Comment: You need to google the word  "inertia"

Comment: Why is this vibration-loss connected to the mass of the object?

Comment: It depends on the direction of the force. If the small force is vertical, it won't move. Frictionless does not mean weightless. But this is just a detail.

Comment: If you're losing energy because of the interaction between them causing vibration, that _is_ friction.

Comment: Newton's first law has nothing to do with mass https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion   "In an inertial reference frame, an object either remains at rest or continues to move at a constant velocity, unless acted upon by a force"

Comment: Why are you trying to invent the scenario that seems to be the exception to the rule?

Comment: This is more about Newton's second law, which I like to write as $\large\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{F}{m}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply a force to any object on a frictionless surface, it will move. There is nothing to prevent this from occurring. You are transferring energy in a sense, where you are using some of your energy to give the object a net kinetic energy, but, in the ideal sense, any force you apply to the object will accelerate it.